# Having problems with my daily load of data through Azure Data Factory to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Cross post from Azure Community: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1323602/having-problems-with-my-daily-load-of-data-through

Excuse me if this is the wrong place to ask this question.

We have a setup where we pull a bunch of data from APIs and load it into Azure blob storage where the code is deployed on Azure function app. After that we flatten the json files in Azure Data Factory and load them into an SQL server database, also on Azure. Recently, I added a new column to be extracted from the API and loaded into the database. Since then, our pipeline has become very inconsistent. The new column is not used in any joins.

The pipelines are completing each run without failure. However, the number of rows loaded into the database is very different between days. Some days, the amount of rows being loaded are the same as expected, but some days it is significantly lower. Something that stands out is that when the failure is happening is that the amount of rows is usually divisible by 250, which is the amount of rows in our partitioning.

When I look into the blob storage, most of the days when the failure is happening we have all the data in the json-files which leads me to believe it is a problem with my flattening component in Data Factory, but there are also instances where the amount of data in the blob storage is lower than expected, which therefore leads me to believe that the problem might be with the APIs.

It seems like Azure had an incident (ID: VLB8-1Z0, https://azure.status.microsoft/sv-se/status/history/) reported the 16th of June affecting both SQL Server and Data Factory, the day before our first instance of the problem. Since then it has been happening with a frequency of every 2-3 days. In that report it states that not all fixes have been implemented yet. Could this be causing our inconsistencies?

Since our load works fine every now and then it also leads me to believe that it is not a problem with our code but rather with some infrastructure.

Up until now I have troubleshot mostly by looking at the logs and the raw data stored in the blob storage without any luck.

I have attached two screenshots in the original post on Azure from our logs in the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please share what approach you are using to flatten your data in ADF?

Comment: We are using a Data Flow in ADF where we unroll the nested values by the key. When the pipeline is not running correctly, i.e. that we are not seeing the same amount of rows as expected, we are also seeing an even amount of rows, so for instance 20000, 22600 etc.

Comment: have you tried the using a audit log table approach looging all the file names with there rwo count? My advise is if you use a stagging table rather coping the data to SQL database you can do it from staging checking staging data VS Audit table.

Comment: Hmm, is that the audit log table where I send it to for instance Log Analytics workspace or to a storage account?

Comment: @Jont_P The Audit table is SQL table it self. so we can use a Stored procedure to Load the data into the staging table and Audit table.
The audit table consist of file_name and the no of records per file.
If you are ok I can post the solution that may help you.

Comment: Ahh right, we already have a Log table in our database where we see how many rows are inserted for each step.

Comment: Great! I would say if have the audit table where you have the record count for each file. first is to load the data into a staging area/table and then load into table .

Comment: Also possibility is that the API you are using to retrieve the data is occasionally not returning the expected number of rows.

Comment: Yeah, we setup two pipelines - one with the new columb and one without to monitor what is going on. Thanks!